# Swift 3 - Core Data - create object

Tags: arrays, object, core-data, swift3

So I am trying to fetch my data from my core data database, put it into objects and then into an array which I then callback.

```
func getCoffeeBrandsFromDB(callback: @escaping (_ dbCoffeeBrands: Array<Any>)-> ()) {
    //create a fetch request, telling it about the entity
    print("running getCBFDB")

    var coffeeBrandArray = Array<Any>()

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CoffeeBrand")

    do {

        let searchResults = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)


        print ("num of results = \(searchResults.count)")


        for brands in searchResults as! [NSManagedObject] {


            let brand = CoffeeBrand()
            brand.dataBaseId = brands.value(forKey: "dataBaseId") as! Int64
            brand.brandName = brands.value(forKey: "brandName") as? String
            brand.numberOfCoffeesNeeded = brands.value(forKey: "numberOfCoffeesNeeded") as! Int32
            coffeeBrandArray.append(brand)
            print("brands virker med \(brand.brandName!)")
        }
        print("CcffeeBrandArray.count is:  \(coffeeBrandArray.count)")
        callback(coffeeBrandArray)
    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
}
```

When I run getCoffeeBrandsFromDB I get this errorlog:

```
running getCBFDB
num of results = 4
2017-02-08 15:47:02.179211 Keebin_development_1[8373:626945] [error] error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'CoffeeBrand'
CoreData: error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'CoffeeBrand' 

2017-02-08 15:47:02.180 Keebin_development_1[8373:626945] -[CoffeeBrand setDataBaseId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000279e80
2017-02-08 15:47:02.189 Keebin_development_1[8373:626945] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CoffeeBrand setDataBaseId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000279e80'
    *** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110c36d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011027721e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ca6f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110bbc005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110bbbb88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Keebin_development_1                0x000000010fc20e5c _TF20Keebin_development_121getCoffeeBrandsFromDBFT8callbackFGSaP__T__T_ + 1804
    6   Keebin_development_1                0x000000010fc2d314 _TFC20Keebin_development_126LoyaltyCardsViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 180
    7   Keebin_development_1                0x000000010fc2d5e2 _TToFC20Keebin_development_126LoyaltyCardsViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001111fca3d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1258
    9   UIKit                               0x000000011123d28f -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 55
    10  UIKit                               0x000000011123db77 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 471
    11  UIKit                               0x000000011123dcee -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 133
    12  UIKit                               0x000000011123eef9 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 874
    13  UIKit                               0x000000011123ffdb -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000111436dd7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 223
    15  UIKit                               0x000000011111fab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001161ffbf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001161f3440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    18  QuartzCore                          0x00000001161f32be _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000116181318 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    20  QuartzCore                          0x00000001161ae3ff _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000111053d9b _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 206
    22  UIKit                               0x000000011185e77c __handleEventQueue + 5672
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110bdb761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110bc098c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110bbfe76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110bbf884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001152f9a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    28  UIKit                               0x000000011105ac68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    29  Keebin_development_1                0x000000010fc3fe5f main + 111
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011434d68d start + 1
    31  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I can't seem to figure out where my problem is. I have created my CoffeeBrand+CoreDataClass.Swift and CoffeeBrand+CoreDataProperties.Swift with the editor-> create NSManaged Object Subclass and as other SO questions/answered has said with the codegen to manual/none.

The two classes mentioned:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(CoffeeBrand)
public class CoffeeBrand: NSManagedObject {

}
```

and:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension CoffeeBrand {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CoffeeBrand> {
        return NSFetchRequest<CoffeeBrand>(entityName: "CoffeeBrand");
    }

    @NSManaged public var brandName: String?
    @NSManaged public var dataBaseId: Int64
    @NSManaged public var id: Int64
    @NSManaged public var numberOfCoffeesNeeded: Int32

}
```

Can someone see where I'm going wrong? Obviously it's in my for-loop but I don't know where/what/how to do it right.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where I went wrong.

I changed  `let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CoffeeBrand")`
to

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CoffeeBrand")
```

this way it is objects I fetch from the DB.

Then it was easy. Now my for-loop is simply:

```
        for brands in searchResults {

        coffeeBrandArray.append(brands)

        }
        callback(coffeeBrandArray)
    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
}
```

And now everything works as it should.